# SQL query for JIRA database to find linked issues

Tags: sql, jira

I am trying to get information directly out of the Jira database. I want to programmatically find all issues that are linked to a particular issue (issue links such as "is developed by", "is continued by" etc.) I have a query which only returns one issue, when I know that there are 8 linked to the main one.

```
select i.pkey 
from jiraschema.jiraissue i
inner join jiraschema.issuelink il ON il.source = i.id
left outer join jiraschema.issuelinktype ilt ON ilt.id = il.linktype
where i.pkey = 'ISS-324'
```

Is there an easy correction to this SQL or is there a better way of querying which will return all linked issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A note: in JIRA v6 and later, the `pkey` column is deprecated and always `null`, you'll have to use the `project` and the `issuenum` columns.

In your SQL, you forgot to link back to the `jiraissue` table to actually get the linked issues.

Here, the query is for the ticket ABCD-1247, where the project ABCD has the ID of 10500 (you can join it from the table `project`):

```
SELECT
  ILT.OUTWARD,
  LI.* -- linked
FROM
  JIRAISSUE I -- parent
INNER JOIN ISSUELINK IL
ON
  IL.SOURCE = I.ID
INNER JOIN ISSUELINKTYPE ILT
ON
  ILT.ID = IL.LINKTYPE
INNER JOIN JIRAISSUE LI -- linked
ON
  LI.ID = IL.DESTINATION
WHERE
  I.PROJECT  = 10500 AND
  I.ISSUENUM = 1247;
```

Comment: This gave me half of what I needed. I realised that I also need to run the query with SOURCE and DESTINATION swapped around i.e. on the 8th line above I use IL.DESTINATION = I.ID and on the 14th line I use LI.ID = IL.SOURCE. The 2 queries together give me exactly what I need

Comment: So you needed the link direction the other way around.